# Single node Cloud Spanner instance exhibiting poor performance

Tags: database, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

We have been using Cloud Spanner with three nodes and getting good performance

```
9,010 mutations
in 0.168 seconds
across 106 rows and 85 columns
or 53,630 mutations per second
```

Since we're still developing, we decided to *only* use a *single* node, to save development costs. Unfortunately, we're experiencing very poor performance. Much less than simply reducing the above by 66%. We're seeing

```
85 mutations mutation
in 1.7 seconds
across 1 row and 85 columns
or 50 mutations per second
```

We go from about 53,630 mutations a second to 50 mutations a second. **Which is a decrease in performance by over 1/1000**, instead of the predicted 1/3.

We did not change a single line of code, and only changed the number of nodes. Does anyone have suggestions or ideas as to why we're seeing such a slow down when going from 3 to 1 cloud spanner nodes?

EDIT: Just to be clear, we're using batch insert and when we "reduced" from 3 instances to 1, we blew away the nodes and started over with 1.

EDIT: corrected semantics ("node" instead of "instance")

Comment: Spanner has a section on how to debug this: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/troubleshooting-performance-regressions

Comment: Hey @TravisWebb thanks for the link! We've been through the provided page, which is much more related to troubleshooting poor performing queries rather then reducing instances to 1. We've ran the same query against 3 instances as we did against 1 and did not the see the scalability in performance as expected. Please let me know if I'm overlooking something.

Comment: 9K mutations in 0.16  seconds across 106 rows? that seems... unlikely. How were you testing? How many mutations batched per/commit; how many threads? Note that spanner commit latency is of the order of 15ms, so 50 commits/sec on one row feels normal

Comment: Just to add, to really load test spanner, you need a large dataset (thousands of rows) and run the load test for O(hours) so that Spanner splits the data so that more than one node is in use.

Comment: @RedPandaCurios Apologies, I updated the question. We are using batch inserts to perform all of this. We tested this by inserting, using the same code against a 3 instance setup and a 1 instance setup, measuring many times with date time and averaging all the measurements.

Comment: Also, we're not really "load testing", but really trying to understand why spanner is yielding only ~1 row/second with 1 instance.

Comment: I am still not sure I understand here...
Are you saying that a single commit with 85 mutations on one row takes 1.7 secs?
(What is a mutation in this context? a changed row/column tuple, or a Mutation object with many changes?

Comment: GCP defines a "mutation" as "any modification of a single cell in a table or index accounts for one mutation, except if you delete a range of rows.". Yes, we are saying "a single commit with 85 mutations on one row takes 1.7 secs". When running only a single instance on Cloud Spanner.

Comment: Wow, ok, thats... unusual! And I assume that the Spanner instance monitoring stats (CPU, read and write QPS) was low at this point, so the instance was not overloaded... You could try to run the same test on a new, clean instance and see if it is just your instance that is the problem... Also, check the monitoring stats in stackdriver for RPC latencies to see exactly where the delay is.

Comment: @RedPandaCurios that's correct, all stats looked as expected. We did a new instance and the same thing was happening. After a few days, we tried again out of desperation, and everything works as expected on a single instance. Please note we didn't change ANY code, so I'm perplexed as to what happened.

I'll look at the stackdriver RPC latencies. Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCP solved what went wrong in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142089717). Copying the relevant portion in case the URL goes down:

> Reducing the number of nodes from 3 to 1 is quite drastic for Cloud Spanner (is comparable to 300 to 100).  The product is delivering high availability, data are replicated in different zones. So what happened in the background is that all the data from all replicas have to be restructured in the background to 1 node. That is relatively big operation that is supposed to take some time. In time background operation finishes, the performance should go back to expected level.

Answer (score 0):

(promoting comment to answer).

I assume that the Spanner instance monitoring stats (CPU, read and write QPS) were low at this point, so the instance was not overloaded...

You could try to run the same test on a new, clean instance and see if it is just your instance that is the problem. It may be that after scaling it down it needs to do some housekeeping. Without knowing your schema, number of rows and operations being performed, its hard to tell.

On other thing, you could check the RPC latency monitoring stats in stackdriver for the Spanner APIs to see exactly where the delay is (although its most likely in Commit).